# MYSQL Repeat without i=i+1

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, repeat

I have the following in a stored procedure

```
DECLARE PUserId int;
SET PUserId = 0;
REPEAT
Does some stuff with it
SET  PUserId = PUserId + 1;
UNTIL PUserId  > 6 END REPEAT;
```

The problem is that my UserIDs are not sequential, example, we have 6 users at the moment and the UserIDs are 1,6,75,234,456.

So if I use UNTIL PUserId  > 6 END REPEAT; it will only work for the first user, to include them all, I have to use UNTIL PUserId  > 456 END REPEAT; which seems pointless running 456 times when I only need to run 6 times.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Yes.  Fetch the rows one at a time from the table (using a cursor for instance).  Or, do what you want in a single query and not in a loop.

Comment: It would help to provide some more information. Do your `UserID`s reside in a table that you are selecting from, or are they provided by user input? What is it that you are doing with the `UserID` (as specific as you can be, unless prohibited)? Depending on your setup you can go about this several different ways.

Comment: Hi, they are in a table, so could a select UserID be used somehow?  and its basically doing an update.